# jquery-cycle left-right alternating

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle

Warning: I don't have any serious JS knowledge.

Currently, we use following code for cycling:

```
    $('#slogans').cycle({
        fx     : 'scrollHorz',
        speed  : 500,
        timeout: 5000,
        next   : '.block_slogans .next',
        prev   : '.block_slogans .prev',
        pause  : 1,
        rev    : 1
    });
```

By itself, it always scrolls to the right, next and previous buttons are handled as expected.

I want to do it that it automatically scrolls right, then left, then right, then left, always with new content, so it looks a little bit surprising, because one usually would expect to see just two items this way, but the hidden one is replaced by a new item.

Answer (score 1):

Below is what you should be using:

```
$('#slogans').cycle({
        fx     : 'scrollLeft',
        speed  : 500,
        timeout: 5000,
        next   : '.block_slogans .next',
        prev   : '.block_slogans .prev',
        pause  : 1,
        rev    : 1
    });
```

**Bottom Line**: You should be using `scrollLeft` instead of `scrollHorz`

[**DEMO**](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/scrollhv.html)

Comment: Why scroll*Left* where it should scroll *left* and *right*? The demo link does not autoscroll at all, but only when clicking the next/previous buttons.

Comment: @MikeL.: you need to control that via manual js. But cycle plugin has the option available